# Is it possible to use a cURL callback function inside a class?

Tags: php, oop, curl

I have a function inside a class that runs a cURL. In the cURL I'm using:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, 'progress');
```

The progress function is inside the class, and using its properties and its methods. (`$this->property`, `$this->method()`)

When I run the script, I get this error message:

```
Warning: curl_exec(): Cannot call the CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION in ...
```

So the question is: Can I do that? And if so, how?

**Edit:**
I have tried to change the code to this:

```
$ref =& $this;
curl_setopt($ch,
    CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION,
    function($resource, $download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded) use ($ref)
    {
        $ref->progress($resource, $download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded);
    }
);
```

But I'm still getting the same error.

**Update:** The solution of @Ohgodwhy is working, just make sure that your callback function doesn't have any errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead, pass in an array with a reference to the object as the first parameter and the function name as the second.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, array($this, 'method'));
```

Comment: I get the same error message. Do I have to do any other changes?

Comment: Version of cURL please

Comment: I was still getting an error because `progress` function had an error, and I didn't see it at first because I had a lot of the `Cannot call the CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` errors... So I fixed the problem on the `progress` function, and it works.